# Need help figuring out .htaccess rules

Tags: .htaccess

I'm pretty new to apache, and I need some help with some .htaccess rewrite rules. Here're the current rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/beta/index\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /beta/index\.php [R=302,L]
```

Basically it redirects any requests to mydomain.com\beta\index.php, except if a filename's specified. This works fine for now.

Here's the problem:

I have a subdomain beta.mydomain.com which I don't want these rules to apply to. Any URL on beta.subdomain.com should be treated normally. However, since the .htaccess is at the server root, it's rules are messing with the beta.subdomain.com as well.

I've tried many different combinations of regex, but I can't figure it out. Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need use something like this (to check if your request was related to specific domain/subdomain):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.mydomain\.com(:80)?$
```

20 seconds were missed... But my answer is better ;)

Comment: Thanks! That did it! Nice avatar, BTW, Terran's OP ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/beta/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^beta\.subdomain\.com 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /beta/index\.php [R=302,L]
```

This ought to do the trick!

Comment: Would this exclude beta.domain.com from the rules, or work only for beta.domain.com? I need the former?

Comment: It would exclude it, I believe. If I messed up, which I possibly did, then change the HTTP_HOST line to: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^beta\.subdomain\.com`

Comment: Ah I did indeed mess up. I have fixed my answer.

Comment: My small confusion was the carat. It can mean not including, or the start of a string in this depending on how it's used, so I had mistakenly assumed the former.

Comment: Sorry about the late response! Thanks for your answer!